# ffmpeg concat output not playing in windows media player

Tags: ffmpeg, windows-media-player, video-conversion

I have a series of short (<3sec) mp4 videos (some with audio, some with no audio) that play fine in all clients. 15 fps, AAC audio. When I use ffmpeg concat, the resulting file plays fine in vlc, however in winmedia it ignores any silence in the audio track. In quicktime it plays all the video, only plays the first audio. I feel it has something to do with syncing video and audio but am new with ffmpeg. If I take the output and recode it with handbrake, it builds a file that works.

```
exec ("ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c  copy finalvideo.mp4");
```

and then I do this:

```
exec ("ffmpeg -i finalvideo.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a libfaac -r 24 output.mp4");
```

Revised with new outputs after ensuring that both source audios have the same encoding (I think)

Info from New Pause File

```
/home/fresh/public_html/ffmpeg/output$ ffmpeg -i /home/fresh/public_html/ffmpeg/output/ENP22122.mp4
ffmpeg version N-61053-gab5d46d-syslint Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Mar  3 2014 13:27:18 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/cpffmpeg --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-decoder=liba52 --enable-  libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-  libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cpffmpeg/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib --enable-version3 --extra-version=syslint
libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/fresh/public_html/ffmpeg/output/ENP22122.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
Duration: 00:00:04.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 63 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1   DAR 4:3], 5 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 96 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Info from new Audio File

```
/home/fresh/public_html/ffmpeg/output$ ffmpeg -i /home/fresh/public_html/ffmpeg/output/ENT22122.mp4
ffmpeg version N-61053-gab5d46d-syslint Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Mar  3 2014 13:27:18 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/cpffmpeg --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-decoder=liba52 --enable-  libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cpffmpeg/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib --enable-version3 --extra-version=syslint
libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/home/fresh/public_html/ffmpeg/output/ENT22122.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
Duration: 00:00:03.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 56 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 6 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 96 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Output from concat command

```
/home/fresh/public_html/ffmpeg/output$ ffmpeg -f concat -i /home/fresh/public_html   /ffmpeg/filesnotime.txt -c  copy /home/fresh/public_html/ffmpeg/finalvideo.mp4
ffmpeg version N-61053-gab5d46d-syslint Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Mar  3 2014 13:27:18 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/cpffmpeg --enable-shared --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-decoder=liba52 --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cpffmpeg/include/ --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib --enable-version3 --extra-version=syslint
libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[concat @ 0x14a2900] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, concat, from '/home/fresh/public_html/ffmpeg/filesnotime.txt':
Duration: 00:00:00.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 102 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 6 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 96 kb/s
Output #0, mp4, to '/home/fresh/public_html/ffmpeg/finalvideo.mp4':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 480x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 6 kb/s, 15 fps, 15360 tbn, 15360 tbc
Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (i[0][0][0] / 0x0069), 44100 Hz, mono, 96 kb/s
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)

frame=  828 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     392kB time=00:00:55.00 bitrate=  58.4kbits/s    
video:81kB audio:289kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 6.031527%
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not very clear. ("Ignores any silence"?) What are the input files like? Can you give the output of simply `ffmpeg -i <inputfile>` for each? Also, please provide the command and console output of `ffmpeg` when you run the command.

Comment: Thank for the quick reply. I am not too familiar with ffmpeg but added the console outputs above. Ignore any silence, I just mean when it joins the files it ignores video clips that have no audio, so if there is no audio, the entire clip seems to be ignored.

Comment: I have updated the console outputs with the new ones after it seems like my source files have the same codec. I don't understand how to run the concat filter, where the file list comes in. Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1. You have some whitespace between `public_html` and `/ffmpeg`. 2. What is the problem with the output now, since both files do have audio? And your duartion (final) indicates you are adding more files.

Comment: Example: http://freshlingo.com/ffmpeg/finalvideo.mp4    I have 3 second audio, 4 second pause for each item. It plays 3 second audios on top of each other, you can see at the 7 sec mark where the next slide starts, the audio should line up with this. For some reason it is ignoring the pauses. thanks  When I run the concat filter, how to I do it for a bunch of file, or do I need to write a script?

Comment: The video plays with audio synch absolutely fine in `Windows Media Player` and `VLC` after I downloaded it. Check your playback on other systems.

Comment: Actually in WMP if you watch, the timecode jumps so that when it is reading 7seconds really only 3 seconds have passed, so that the entire clip plays in less than half the time. In VLC if you play from beginning, near the end it inserts random audio from the beginning. Sorry to keep at this but I feel like I am close. Can you comment on my question about concat filter and how to do it, if I need a script.

Comment: To see all concatenation methods see [this](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The `concat demuxer` you are using works only if the files have same number of streams each. Read [this](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) documentation.

In other words you will need to mux in (silent) audio into the files which have no audio. Try this:

```
 ffmpeg -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -i ENP22122.mp4 -shortest \
 -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict -2 newmuxedfile.mp4
```

You can then concatenate the newmuxedfile.mp4 provided the codecs are the same. The demuxer will not work if codecs differ. So here i used `aac` as in your other file. If the concat fails for codecs differing, use the `concat filter` instead.

```
ffmpeg -i ENA22122.mp4 -i newmuxedfile.mp4 -filter_complex \
'[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]' \
-map '[v]' -map '[a]' -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 output.mp4
```

Note that you **can** use `-c:v copy` if the video codecs are the same.

To see all concatenation methods see [this](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files) documentation.

Comment: Thank you. I have now got my source files in exactly the same format and still have output problems with concat. Rather than post another bunch of outputs, is there someway I contact you? and perhaps see if you want to consult on this?

Comment: Have you tried the concat filter? Please do edit your question to add the new console outputs and your command. There are many experts here who are all happy to "consult" for free.

Comment: Update: 1. Using concat/filter on my source files and output works perfect all platforms. 2. Using concat/filter, join two files in batches, then use concat on those files output fails. 3. Concat on other source files works. Leads me back to my source files as the problem but they all seem the same codec. Question: Do you know what the limit is with concat/filter? I seem to hit an error 'too many inputs' above 3 files.