# Join multiple video files. Two witout audio and three with audio

Tags: ffmpeg

i am trying to join 5 videos. 2 of them do not have audio streams.

I get this error :

```
Stream specifier ':1' in filtergraph description [0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] [2:0] [2:1] 
[3:0] [3:1] [4:0] [4:1] concat=n=5:v=1:a=1 [v] [a] matches no streams.
```

I use this arguments

```
ffmpeg -y  -i "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp83A2.tmp.avi"  -i "C:\Users\alex\AppDat\Local
\Temp\tmp83C2.tmp.avi" -i "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp83F2.tmp.avi"  -i "C:\Users
\alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8412.tmp.avi" -i "C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8442.tmp.avi"  -filter_complex "[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] [2:0] [2:1] [3:0] [3:1]` [4:0] [4:1] concat=n=5:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]"  "C:\Users\alex\Documents`
\output.avi"
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

The stream specifier `:1` refers to the audio stream which you **do not have** in all files. So it gives an error. You should mux in blank/silent audio to be able to concatenate.

See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/729622/ffmpeg-concat-output-not-playing-in-windows-media-player) recent post which deals with how to mux in silent audio before concatenating.

```
ffmpeg -y  -i <inputfile1>  -i <inputfile2> -i <inputfile3> -i <inputfile4> -i <inputfile5> -filter_complex "[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] [2:0] [2:1] [3:0] [3:1] [4:0] [4:1] concat=n=5:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]"  <encoding_parameters_here> <outputfile>
```

This should work but you should use some encoding parameters if the codecs of the various input files vary. If using `aac` for audio, also use `-strict -2`.